# Send complete string array at once

Tags: c

I'm trying to send some Hayes commands (AT commands) to my modem through a serial line.
The function I call is `post_request::open()`. Within this method there is a static commands string array holding the commands to configure the connection profile.
My first question is: Should I use a more "flexible" approach on creating the commands list?
I always need to send these eight commands to my modem. Of course the url, content_type and content_length vary.
Maybe somebody can show me a better way to do it.

```
int post_request::open(const char *url, unsigned content_length, const char *content_type)
{
    static const char *commands[] =
    {
        // Connection profile
        "AT^SISS=0,conId,0;",
        // HTTP
        "AT^SISS=0,srvType,Http;",
        // User Agent
        "AT^SISS=0,hcUsrAgent," USER_AGENT_STRING ";",
        // HTTP method
        "AT^SISS=0,hcMethod,1;",
        // Placeholder for modem type bdx80
        "AT;",
        // Placeholder for address
        "AT;",
        // Placeholder for number of bytes sent
        "AT;",
        // Placeholder for content type
        "AT;",
        // Open internet session with configured profile
        "AT^SISO=0\r",
        NULL
    };

    // Some code...
    if (modem->modem_type == bdx80)
        commands[4] = "AT^SISS=0,secOpt,-1;";

    // Some more code...
    commands[6] = "AT^SISS=0,hcContLen,",content_length,";";

    // Code for content_type settings...

    int error = send_commands(modem, timeout, commands);
    if (error)
        return error;

}
```

After I finished the connection profile setup, I call `send_commands()`.
I have a third party library which does the uart transmit & receive stuff.
The function I call within `send_commands()` is `uart_tx()`.
Question: What do I need to do, to call `uart_tx()` correctly? I want the complete commands list to be sent at once.

Thx

```
static int
send_commands(modem_t *modem, unsigned timeout, const char *commands[])
{
    // determine size of commands pointer array
    unsigned len = ???;
    // Send commands through serial line
    if (uart_tx(modem->port, ???, &len, timeout))
        return TIMEOUT;
}


/**
* Sends count bytes.
* @param port       The serial port.
* @param buf[in]    Pointer to the buffer containing the bytes to be sent.
* @param count[in,out]  Pointer to the value containing the number of bytes to send
*           (in) and the number of bytes actually sent (out).
* @param time_to_wait   The maximum amount of time the task should block waiting
*        for count bytes to be sent should the transmit queue be full at some time.
* @return 0 on successful transmission, 1 on timeout
*/
unsigned uart_tx(SerialPort port, const void *buf, unsigned *count, unsigned time_to_wait)
```

Comment: Do you want to concatenate the strings from array to one, and send with one command, or is it fine to send them one-by-one with multiple `uart_tx` calls?

Comment: Also note that `    commands[6] = "AT^SISS=0,hcContLen,",content_length,";";` does not do what you think it does... comma does not concatenate strings in C. You need a buffer (either local `char buf[enough];` if lifetime of local variable is enough for you, or allocated with `char *buf = malloc(enough);`. And then you need to use `snprintf(buf, enough, ....)` to construct your command string. Welcome to the wonderful world of C string handlinng ;)

Comment: @hyde I want to concatenate the strings and send it with one command. Thx for spotting the mistake

Comment: To get you started, to iterate through `commands`, you need loop like `for(int command_index=0; commands[command_index]; ++command_index) { ... }`. You can do this twice, first round to add up how much space you need, or just have "big enough" buffer and test for overflow when copying.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to just concatenate (memcpy or strcat or whatever) all the commands into a single buffer before sending them out.

Comment: I'd think he should wait for OK response from the modem between sending the commands.

Comment: This is not really an answer - it should probably just be a comment.

Comment: @hyde: I don't wont to send every single command to the modem and wait for the response. I want them grouped together and receive only one single response for the whole commands. The commands are already prepared for that. The last command is sent with an '\r', that's how the modem recognizes the end of the AT sequence